# How can I set up my routing in mvc project to work properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

if the url https://search.ridgewater.edu/ScreeningCheckinForm/ my form is not do the ajax call to autofill firstname and last name.
 but if the https://search.ridgewater.edu/ScreeningCheckinForm/SCREENING_CHECKIN_FORM/Create
my form would do ajax call.
This is my rout config

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SCREENING_CHECKIN_FORM", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and the form I created is in create.cshtml and the controller I use is SCREENING_CHECKIN_FORMController
What did I do wrong?
Please help

Comment: Check in browser dev tools (press F12) and can you see network request ? is your app in in dir /ScreeningCheckinForm?

Comment: Hi, I will check the network tab again. Yes  the app is in ScreeningCheckinForm folder. Thanks you !

Comment: I work around by adding an index.cshtml and make it as a default/ first page. And my form works correctly now. still don't get it.